# How to access the Javascript variable value outside the script tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to access the Javascript variable value outside the Javascript tag.

```js
function getprices(input) {
    return input.match(/[0-9]+/g);
}
var subtotals = get_getprices('%GLOBAL_OrderTotal%');
var Grand_total = subtotals[0];
```

```html
<img height="0" width="0" border="0" src="http://testing.com?merchantId=M1&orderNo=%%GLOBAL_OrderId%%&saleAmount=I want the Grand+Total Value here">
```

Comment: give the image an id and access it with `window.getElementById('id here').src='your string';`

Comment: I would recommend to create the whole image with the correct source by javascript, so it does not get loaded with an unwanted src before changing it.

Comment: @Lain can u explain in answer in little detail what do you mean by "does not get loaded with an unwanted src before changing it"

Comment: @Alex: The image might get loaded before changing the src attribute, depending on when and how the function gets called - which again might lead to an unwanted or unexpected, yet for sure uneeded, outcome.

Comment: @Alex: Added an example below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to update the `src` property on that `img` element. Let's suppose you gave the `img` an `id` *(you don't have to, there are other ways to select it, but I'm keeping it simple)*:

```
<img id="the-image" height="0" width="0" border="0" src="http://testing.com?merchantId=M1&orderNo=%%GLOBAL_OrderId%%&saleAmount=I want the Grand+Total Value here">
```

Then:

```
function getprices(input) {
    return input.match(/[0-9]+/g);
}
var subtotals = getprices('%%GLOBAL_OrderTotal%%'); // <=== Changed to `getprices`, was `get_getprices`
var Grand_total=subtotals[0];
var img = document.getElementById("the-image");
img.src = "http://testing.com?merchantId=M1&orderNo=%%GLOBAL_OrderId%%&saleAmount=" + Grand_total;
```

It looks like `Grand_total` will always be a number, but for the general case where it might not be, , be sure to use `encodeURIComponent` (it doesn't do any harm even if it is a number):

```
img.src = "http://testing.com?merchantId=M1&orderNo=%%GLOBAL_OrderId%%&saleAmount=" + encodeURIComponent(Grand_total);
```

---

If you didn't use an `id` on the `img`, that's fine, you can use any CSS selector via `document.querySelector`. That's supported by all modern browsers, and also IE8.

---

Note that there are *other* issues with that code, though, not least that `getprices` looks fairly suspect.

Comment: get_getprices should probably be getprices aswell.

Comment: @Lain: Seems likely, yeah. I'm not seeing how `getprices` would actually work, unless `%%GLOBAL_OrderTotal%%` is a template item that's replaced server-side, but...

Comment: I see that you have set the id, that may not be required.

Comment: @MegaMind: True. It's just an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`document.getElementsByTagName("img")[***index of the image tag***].src = "<THE STRING>"+<THE VARIABLE>+"<THE REMAINING STRING>";`

or assign an id to the `<img>` and use

`document.getElementById("***id of the image***").src = ""++"";

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to assign your value to src of img in your javascript

```
$("#imgNeeded").attr("src",".../"+Globalvalue)
```

As T.J. Crowder said. make sure you encode URI if your variable contain something other than number

Comment: Keep in mind that this will affect all images on the document.

Comment: Yes but the OP did not specify. So assume there is one image.

Answer (score 1):

The problem the provided approaches share is, that how they are, your image will get loaded with the unwanted source before changed:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function getprices(input){return input.match(/[0-9]+/g)};

            function changeSrc(){
                var tE = document.querySelector("img[src*='saleAmount=']");
                var tS = getprices('anyPrice1');

                if (tE && tS) tE.src += encodeURIComponent(tS[0]);
            };
        </script>
</head>

<body onload = 'changeSrc()'>
    <img height = '0' width = '0' border = '0' src = 'http://JUSTTOSHOWtesting.com?merchantId=M1&orderNo=%%GLOBAL_OrderId%%&saleAmount=' onerror = 'console.log(this.src)'>
</body>
```

Your console will log two calls:

```
- GET http://justtoshowtesting.com/?merchantId=M1&orderNo=%%GLOBAL_OrderId%%&saleAmount= net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
- GET http://justtoshowtesting.com/?merchantId=M1&orderNo=%%GLOBAL_OrderId%%&saleAmount=1 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

So what you could do is placing a placeholder, until you have the source you need:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function getprices(input){return input.match(/[0-9]+/g)};

            function createSrc(){
                var tE = document.querySelector("ins[src*='saleAmount=']");
                var tS = getprices('anyPrice1');

                if (tE && tS){
                    var tI = document.getElementById('iPlaceholder');
                    if (!tI){
                        tI = document.createElement('img');
                        tI.id = 'iPlaceholder';
                        tI.onerror = function(){console.log(this.src)};
                        tE.parentNode.insertBefore(tI, tE.nextSibling);
                    };
                    tI.src = tE.getAttribute('src') + encodeURIComponent(tS[0]);
                };
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = 'createSrc()'>
        <ins src = 'http://JUSTTOSHOWtesting.com?merchantId=M1&orderNo=%%GLOBAL_OrderId%%&saleAmount='></ins>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now your console will merely log one call:

```
- GET http://justtoshowtesting.com/?merchantId=M1&orderNo=%%GLOBAL_OrderId%%&saleAmount=1 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```